# Equivalent of ViewScope using CDI Conversation scope

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, view-scope, conversation-scope

Is it possible that i begin my conversation each time the page is loaded and end it when i move out of the page. How do i use conversation scope of CDI to work exactly like View Scope. I don't want to use seam-faces or my faces Codi extensions . I also don't currently have the option to switch to JSF 2.2.

Comment: Use OmniFaces [`ViewScoped`](http://wiki.omnifaces.googlecode.com/hg/javadoc/org/omnifaces/cdi/ViewScoped.html) annotation. If you still refuse to do it (very odd, indeed), just copy/paste/adapt the code to your project and use it.

Comment: thanks i will try using it. :) But i was looking for an equivalent in conversation scope

Comment: You already must understand that `@ConversationScoped` is not `@ViewScoped`. While you can start the conversation when accessing to the view and kill it when moving out of the same view emulating the behavior of `@ViewScoped`, the user can naively just remove the `cid` query string parameter and you're in problems :).